# Does std::any_cast call destructor? How the cast works?

Tags: c++, stdany, anycast

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

class c {
public:
    c() :a{ 0 } { cout << "constructor\n"; }
    c(int aa) :a{ aa } { cout << "Constructor\n"; }
    ~c() { cout << "destructor\n"; }
    int get() { return a; }
private:
    int a;
};

auto main()->int
{
    any a{ 5 };
    cout << any_cast<int>(a) << '\n';
    
    a.emplace<c>(3);
    cout << '!' << any_cast<c>(a).get() << '\n';
    //des
    cout << '\n';
    
    a.emplace<c>(9);
    cout << '!' << any_cast<c>(a).get() << '\n';
    //des
}
```

destructor called after each any_cast.
and, below code makes run-time error.
I think the cause is any_cast(C)'s work pipeline is might be like
`~C() then X(C) ERROR!!C doesn't exist`
any_cast really work like that?

I add blow codes and make run-time error.

```
class X {
public:
    X() :a{ 0 } { cout << "xonstructor\n"; }
    X(c& aa) :a{ aa.get() } { cout << "Xonstructor\n"; }
    ~X() { cout << "Xdestructor\n"; }
    int get() { return a; }
private:
    int a;
};

auto main()->int
{
    any a{ 5 };
    cout << any_cast<int>(a) << '\n';
    
    a.emplace<c>(3);
    cout << '!' << any_cast<X>(a).get() << '\n';
//runtime error after '!'
    cout << '\n';
    
    a.emplace<c>(9);
    cout << '!' << any_cast<X>(a).get() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `a.emplace<c>(3);` is a typo. You want `a.emplace<X>(3);`

Comment: @super I don’t think that’s a typo … I think OP intends to call the converting constructor in the `any_cast`.

Comment: @super My Idea is make a to c with 3 then cout it by X with any_cast. It wasn't typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *copying* a `c` (or `X`) from the one within the `std::any`. That copy is destroyed at the end of the expression, after having been streamed out.

`any_cast` does not do any conversion. It throws if you ask it for a type different to the one it stores. When you have emplaced a `c` and asked for an `X`, it throws `std::bad_any_cast`, because `X` is not `c`.

Comment: thx. any_cast is just a value-fetch-tool. not a convertor! am I right?

Comment: yes, it is only for extracting the value that is stored in the any